# Determining if a vector is in the row space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I am asked to determine whether the vector

$x = [1, 1, -2, 1, -1]$

is in the row space of the matrix

$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & -2 & 2 & 0 \\
    1 & 2 & 2 & -6 & 0 \\
    2 & 3 & 0 & -4 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

can I just show show that the equation $A^T=x^T$ has a consistent solution?

(i.e. Does showing that $x^T$ is in the column space of $A^T$ also show that $x$ is in the row space of $A$?)

Comment: Your notation isn't quite right but yes you can take the transpose to turn the problem into one about the column space. This is overkill if you look carefully at row 1 and row 4 of $A$.

Comment: @JessicaK Ok, I see that $x$ is a linear combination of row 1 and row 4, but I was just wondering if this could be used as a general way of solving this type of question. Where is my notation off? I made an edit correcting an error, I don't know if that is what you were referring to

Comment: While in this particular case the answer is quite easy to see by inspection of the rows, the systematic method would be to use elimination to obtain a basis of the row space, and then check whether the given vector is a linear combination of the basis so obtained. If you use the basis given by the nonzero rows of a matrix in reduced echelon form equivalent to the original matrix, it is quite easy to see whether a given vector is in their span.

Comment: @CornOnTheKob You want something like $A^{T}v^{T} = x^{T}$. As written now, it doesn't make sense that you are equating a matrix with a vector.